# Meaning of Fuzzy Parameter in Lucene

Tags: lucene

As stated in [the Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches) there is a parameter that enables for specifying similarity required for a match. The value of is between 0 and 1, with a value closer to 1 only terms with a higher similarity will be matched. For example: roam~0.8

Know I wonder whether this parameter is meant in a relative sence, i.e. for a string that is longer, the string edit distance might be higher and there is still a match. Or, is this a meant as an absolute value, i.e. only up to x substitutions/deletion/insertions are allowed to make a match happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search for `term~sim` will find all terms which have an edit distance of less than `length(term) * (1- sim)`. So `roam~0.8` will find all terms with an edit distance of less than 4*(1-.8)=.8 of roam.

EDIT:

The term must be longer than 1/(1 - sim). So a search for `roam~.8` won't do anything fuzzy, because things with a similarity of .8 must have a length of at least 5.

Comment: Thanks. And do you know what are the cost for substitutions/deletion/insertions, are they equally 1 as suggested by Levenshtein or are they slightly different?

Comment: @bertolami: yes, it is an exact Levenshtein implementation. You can see the method `Similarity` in the `FuzzyTermEnum` class for the code.